# iPad UIWebview showing all contents in top-left corner (1 fourth of screen)?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, twitter, uiwebview

In my universal app when i click button am opening a new view controller with 2 xib (one is for iPad and another is for iPhone  .Auto layout enabled for both xib's).

Am trying to load a html string as url in iPhone and iPad. In iPhone its coming correctly (Full screen) and in iPad its coming only top-left corner .

This is my code

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSString *str=@"<a class='twitter-timeline' href='https://twitter.com/hashtag/aphrsindia' data-widget-id='501341258330025985'>#aphrsindia Tweets</a><script>!function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],p=/^http:/.test(d.location)?'http':'https';if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src=p+'://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js';fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document,'script','twitter-wjs');</script>";

       [_webview loadHTMLString:str baseURL:nil];

       [self initializeNavBarItems];

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
}
```

[iPad screenshot link](http://postimg.org/image/eypykrznj/)

Please help me ..

Comment: May sound stupid, but in your xib the webview is spanned over the whole UI? Otherwise try to disable auto-layout and set the height&width manually, to see if something changes.

Edit: maybe provide a screenshot of your iPad's xib

Comment: i have done that before no change at all

Answer (score 1):

Problem: This twitter url adding a iframe with width:520px and thats the reason .

Solution:
I have created a html file with style

```
<style>
iframe#twitter-widget-0{

    width: 100% !important;
    height: 100% !important;
}
</style>
```

and  in body i have added rest of the url string .

Comment: I guess Twitter sees the browser as an iPhone and giving out iPhone layout. Try to set a custom User Agent suitable for iPad and see if that works out.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your content in html is correctly formated. And when you navigate on this view controller, check that you load correct .xib. Like :

```
YourViewController *yourController;
if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)
    yourController = [[YourViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"YourViewController_iPad" bundle:nil];
else
    yourController = [[YourViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"YourViewController_iPhone" bundle:nil];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:yourController animated:TRUE];
```

Comment: i figure it out the problem, its like twitter is setting width 520px for iframe.but i dont know the solution !!! .ryt now am trying dynamic css injection

Comment: Great... @johnmikemike